AngularJS file upload issue: Stuck at "No file selected" when clicking "Load File"
I'm encountering an issue with an AngularJS application where I have a file input field and a button to upload the selected file. However, when I select a file and click the "Load File" button, the application gets stuck at displaying the alert message "No file selected" and doesn't proceed further.
Here's the relevant codes:
index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Employee Management</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>Employee Management</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="file" ng-model="file" id="file" accept=".txt">
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="uploadFile()">Load File</button>
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" ng-click="loadFromDatabase()">Show Youngest and Eldest Employee</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table_all" ng-show="showTableAll">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                            <th>Designation</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                            <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{employee.age}}</td>
                            <td>{{employee.designation}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <table class="table_youngesteldest" ng-show="showTableYoungestEldest">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Designation</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                            <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{employee.designation}}</td>
                            <td>{{employee.age}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


app.js:
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.showTableAll = false;
        $scope.showTableYoungestEldest = false;

        $scope.uploadFile = function () {
            if (!$scope.file) {
                alert('No file selected.');
                return;
            }

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', $scope.file);

            $http.post('/api/Employee/UploadFile', formData, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
            }).then(function (response) {
                alert('Loaded Success');
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error); // Log the entire error object
                alert(error.data.message);
            });

            $scope.showTableAll = true;
            $scope.showTableYoungestEldest = false;
        };

        $scope.loadFromDatabase = function () {
            $http.get('/api/Employee/YoungestAndEldest')
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.employees = response.data;
                }, function (error) {
                    alert('Error loading data from database:', error);
                });

            $scope.showTableAll = false;
            $scope.showTableYoungestEldest = true;
        };
    });



